# Does Matlab R2015 use GPU?

Tags: matlab

Mathworks seems to be working on making better use of GPUs and I am wondering at what stage they are at in R2015. Does it automatically use GPU or do I need to program Matlab somehow to make use of my GPU? I have Nvidia GTX860M and it would be a pity for it to idle away while I sit and wait for Matlab to execute scripts. Do I still need to get an add-on for GPU for Matlab R2015?

If someone is currently using GPU in their Matlab computing, can you post some relevant links with what I have to go to set it up (preferably for R2015, if it makes any difference)? Whenever I search I come across different instructions made for Matlab from R2006 to R2012 and I wonder if they are still relevant for more recent releases.

Comment: "You can use GPUs with MATLAB through Parallel Computing Toolbox", referring to NVIDIA CUDA in Matlab, see http://de.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gpu.html. HTH

Comment: I personally find [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/examples/illustrating-three-approaches-to-gpu-computing-the-mandelbrot-set.html) very useful in showing the different approaches to using the GPU in MATLAB. The easiest thing you can do is use [`gpuArray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/gpuarray_object.html). Also make sure you have the [CUDA toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it automatically use GPU?

No, you have to make the decision. Using the gpuArray function you decide to copy the data to the graphic card memory. Any data stored there is processed by the gpu (as long as the function is supported, otherwise you get an error), any data stored in your main memory is processed by the CPU.

For more information how to use it, start reading here http://de.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gpu.html